# How to pass function's parameter to $http post in angular js so that this value can sent through $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

//How to pass function's parameter to $http post in angular js so that this value can sent through $http

```
$scope.abc=function(i,d)
{
     alert(id);//Getting value
     $http.post('abc.php?flag=pqr', 
            {
                'q'     : i,//value is not posting
                's'     : d ////value is not posting
                //How to send value of i and d to abc.php page
             })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert(data);
                alert("Product has been Submitted Successfully");
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                alert("Something went wrong please try again");
            });
     }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the caller of the function?

Comment: <a ng-href=add.php?q=edit&i= '{{x.i}}'&d='{{x.d}}'>//add.php where controller is called and these two value are getting in controller function.The issue is these value are not sent using $http